# hosts file on windows azure website

Tags: asp.net, azure, hosts-file

I have a ASP.NET website in windows azure that uses a web reference. I use azure as my QA environment and on QA, the site should connect to the QA web reference. On my previous QA environment, I used hosts file entry to point the web reference domain name to the QA IP address. but after migrating to windows azure, I don't know how to point the web reference to the QA IP address. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You might need to migrate web reference project to Azure too! and the get exact website URL for web ref project and use that in website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can affect hosts in Azure.

Instead, I suggest using SlowCheetah.  It is an open source project that will transform your configuration file (or any XML file) based on the build you are targeting.  I use it to change the connection string in web.config for QA and PROD builds.

> This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration. It also adds additional tooling to help you create XML transforms.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

You can set your web reference to be dynamic, so that the specifics are loaded from your web.config.  See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335499/141172